# Can I use Authenticator instead of phone number for Gmail 2FA?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, gmail

I want to enable Two-Factor Authentication for my gmail accunt, but when setting this up it asks for my phone number.

I don't have a phone (that I want to connect to Gmail), is there another way to enable 2FA? More specifically I'd like to use Google Authenticator, is that possible?

I'm actually surprised that Google doesn't clearly offer Google Authenticator as a 2FA method right away.

Comment: you can, because I do use Google Authenticator for  it. However, I don't remember how did I set it, maybe it was with a procedure similar to Lukas' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Authenticator worked for me - but it was a little bit tricky.

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security and start the process of enabling 2FA
2. Google required me to enter my phone number - I could not find a way to enable Google Authentiactor without prior entry of a phone number. So do this and enable 2FA.
3. Once 2FA is active, you can add a second authentication mode (say Google Authenticator App).
4. Now you can make the Google Authenticator App your default and remove the phone number from the list of 2FA providers.

<sub>I don't know why there is no simpler way to enable the Google Authenticator App - this is really a bit strange. This answer is based solely on my own experience; it might be that I missed something.</sub>